# Suboperations,k-ary operation

Tags: elementary-number-theory, logic, group-isomorphism, binary-operations

[Here](https://u.osu.edu/friedman.8/files/2014/01/ImpossibleCnt090217-2a5ewhm.pdf), on page 4,

the phrase "the same ≤ r-element suboperations up to isomorphism"

means s-element suboperations for some **fixed** s≤r?

Is this interpretation correct?

Moreover, how can I see that

> The strongest of these is ≤r-isomorphism, and the weakest of these is operational r-isomorphism.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most obvious reading is that it is ${\bf every}\ s \leq r$, and this seems to be borne out by the definition of $\leq \! \! r$-${\it element\ function}$ in Def 1.2 and that of ${\it suboperation}$ in the preceding paragraph.  Cf. ${\it operation}$ in Def 1.1.

Now, maybe this already answers your second question, but anyway, here is a way to break down the problem: There are four obvious pairs that you could compare separately, for example $\leq \!\! r$-isomorphism vs $r$-isomorphism, and $r$-isomorphism vs operational $r$-isomorphism.  I would expect to find that 'not operational' is stronger than 'operational,' both for $r$ and for $\leq$, and that $\leq\!\! r$ is stronger than $r$, both for 'operational' and for 'non-operational'.

Comment: In fact, I do not understand why precisely it holds that "≤r is stronger than r". You compare more items in "≤r" then in r. So less operations are in the relation  "≤r-isomorphic" then in "r-isomorphic".

Comment: Yes, that is what the author means by $\it stronger$. Similarly to how we would say $<$ is stronger than $\leq$, and $=$ is stronger than $\leq$, as relations of real numbers.

Comment: Could you please also explain to me what he means on page 2 by the last two sentences: "...For the second claim, looking at the f:" I.e. how the lower bound $2^{|E|}$ follows? What is it lower bound for?

Comment: He means the second claim of the theorem, namely that there are $2^{|E|}$ operators $f : E^k \rightarrow E$ in "higher dimensions," i.e. when $k \geq 2$. He shows the lower bound by arguing there are at least as many in dimension-$k$ as there are in dimension-1; thus reducing it to the dimension-1 case, which he just proved using the trees called $T[< x]$.

Comment: Incidentally, your question might draw more interest if you indicated somewhere what the document is called, who wrote it, and some of the surprising new results it claims.